# In rails, How to reload a partial using ajax, only if particular condition is satisfied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application have posts and comments. I want to update the comments using ajax. And I want to reload the comments partial only if the number of comments for the post is increased. So, I thought of creating an action, which checks the number of comments for the post, if the comments count is increased, I will reload the partial, otherwise I dont want to reload it. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Architecture-wise it will be better to use server push technology. E.g. Faye https://github.com/faye/faye

The decision you're talking about is called polling. This is acceptable if you don't have highload app.